# sourceFileExcludes tag in the maven-javadoc-plugin

Tags: maven, javadoc

Does anyone has an example how to use the `sourceFileExcludes` element in the [Maven Javadoc Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/)? I've tried the following, but cannot get it to work:

```xml
<sourceFileExcludes>
    <sourceFileExclude>**/internal/*</sourceFileExclude>
    <sourceFileExclude>**/Model/*</sourceFileExclude>
</sourceFileExcludes>
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14518220/1281433) is a bit newer, but it has some more information…

Answer (score 2):

Have you specified [excludePackageNames](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#excludePackageNames), cause based on [the docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#sourceFileExcludes) you should use them instead of what you've written.

```
<excludePackageNames>*.internal:org.acme.exclude1.*:org.acme.exclude2</excludePackageNames>
```

which seemed to be more approriate.

Comment: Actually I want to use sourceFileExcludes tag to exclude the specific classes.like <sourceFileExcludes>
    <sourceFileExclude>com/example/internal/Test1</sourceFileExclude>
     <sourceFileExclude>com/example/Model/Test2</sourceFileExclude>, is that possible. Thanks
</sourceFileExcludes>

Comment: @khmarbaise I read the documentation that you posted, but I'm not sure why excludePackageNames would be preferable (unless subpackage or subpackages are specified, in which case they're ignored).  Can you clarify at all?

Answer (score 0):

It might just not be working at the moment. There is bug logged in the plugin issue tracker - [MJAVADOC-365](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC-365)